# Zip list of dictionaries

Tags: python

Is there a way to zip a list of dictionaries by value?

For example:

```
d = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3, 'b': 5}]
list(zip(*d))
>>> [('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b')]
```

We can zip a dictionary by key as any other list of tuples, but I wanted the following result:

[(1, 3), (2, 5)]

Is this achievable using zip? Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Did you mean to expect `[(1, 3), (2, 5)]`?

Comment: If your expected output is `[(1, 2), (3, 5)]` then that's not zipping at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map the list of dicts to `dict.values` for zipping:

```
list(zip(*map(dict.values, d)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
list(zip(*(dic.values() for dic in d)))
```

Gives:

```
[(1, 3), (2, 5)]
```

Documentation [reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values).

**EDIT:**

If you *actually* wanted `[(1, 2), (3, 5)]`, that is just the keys of an iterable of dictionaries as tuples, then this is how:

```py
[tuple(dic.values()) for dic in d]
```

But that is not what is commonly referred to as "zipping".